# Swagger XML Comments for ASP .NET Web Application

Tags: asp.net, swagger

I have sucessfully implemented swagger on my ASP.NET Web Application api, and works like a charm. Now i wnat to add comments on fields, i have searched and i can only see examples on ASP.Net Core web Api, how can i achieve the same in a ASP.NET we Application api.

Comment: What library did you use to add Swagger to your ASP.NET web app? Did you check its documentation?

Comment: I used swachbuckle, and all other documentation i am get is for swashbuckle for asp.net core

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41957572/how-to-show-xml-comments-of-class-properties-in-swagger-mvc-6-web-api-jsonresul